# Turning off Toyota Yaris ABS system

Tags: toyota, abs, yaris

I unplugged the ABS fuse from my Toyata Yaris 2006 1.5 Hatchback CE to turn off the ABS system which was giving me trouble when trying to stop on snowy/icy roads.

The car stops much better now, so that problem is fixed.
However the 50Amp fuse says `ABS1/VSC1` and I don't know what the `VSC1` stands for.

Is it something important I might miss later on?

Comment: Just hearing about messing with an ABS system is like fingernails on a chalkboard to me.

Comment: @Ppoggio if you know what you are doing, there's nothing wrong with driving without abs. Old cars didn't have it... And in this case it actually made it less safe to drive since it was always turning on for no reason

Comment: If you have an accident and it is discovered that you disabled some of the safety features of your car, won't you be in trouble with the law and your insurance company?

Comment: Seems like a good question to post by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSC stands for Vehicle Stability Control. It's the part which works in conjunction with the ABS to keep your vehicle stable during a bad braking situation. It also will help you in corners and such which might be a little too much for your vehicle. You decide whether it's important to you or not.